# How is it possible download an iOS application to Desktop?

Tags: ios-appstore

We have an app and many user downloaded it to "Desktop". How is it possible? What does it exactly mean. I see this in `AppStore Connect`.

[image]

Comment: Did you try clicking on the `?` ahead of the Devices title to see the help text?

Comment: This is a screenshot from App Store Connect.  To answer this question, the author would need to know how Apple defines 'desktop' in this context.

Comment: Tried `?`. No relevant I found. So how Apple define 'desktop'?